# check if a files mime-type matches it's extension in php

Tags: php, mime-types, file-extension

Is there any way to check that a files mime-type matches it's extension in php ?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php. This function allows you to detect the file's mime-type.

Comment: I know how to get a files mime type as well as it's extension. What that page does not explain is how to check if a files mime-type matches it's extension.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147931/how-do-i-determine-the-extensions-associated-with-a-mime-type-in-php

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of known mime types with corresponding extensions, using the [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function and looking up the extension in an array is simple. There are problems, however; a comprehensive list would be large and likely become outdated fairly quickly, and sniffing mime types is generally considered a difficult problem with [inaccurate solutions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php#79063).