# PHP: File extension to MIME type?

Tags: php, file, mime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine the extension(s) associated with a MIME type in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147931/how-do-i-determine-the-extensions-associated-with-a-mime-type-in-php)

I'm aware of how to get the MIME type of a given *file*, but is there a way to do it given only an *extension*?

Example input:

```
jpg
```

Example output:

```
image/jpeg
```

Comment: Does [this comment](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php#107798) from the PHP docs help?

Comment: I do not think it's a duplicate, as drrcknlsn wants to get the mime type from the extension while the question (which this is marked as duplicate of) does the opposite, finding the extension for a mime type.

Comment: Clearly, as @Alex says. How is this a duplicate of the linked answer, if that one wants the (*list of*!) extensions for a MIME type, while this one needs the inverse function: get *the* MIME type for *an* extension?!

Comment: should help : https://gist.github.com/nimasdj/801b0b1a50112ea6a997

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147931/how-do-i-determine-the-extensions-associated-with-a-mime-type-in-php) to get info about which extension is which mime type, but of course please be aware that this won't be very accurate (e.g. possible gif file on png extension..)

Comment: I ended up rolling my own method, but thanks for letting me know about `/etc/mime.types`!  That was the ticket.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant solution I've seen for Apache environments is http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php#107798

Comment: Even if you aren't using Apache, it would be easy enough to get the `mime.types` file and query directly against it. I was going to suggest creating a temporary file and querying against it in the normal way, but loading a list of mime types and doing a lookup would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the Fileinfo extension installed, but from PHP documentation, it seems like Fileinfo might give you that information, which was previously given by the deprecated function `mime_content_type()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

Comment: `fileinfo` would need a file...

Comment: @drrcknlsn Good point. I missed the most important part of the question. Thanks for pointing it out.