# php random image file name

Tags: php

Okay im using a snippet I found on google to take a users uploaded image and put it in my directory under Content

But Im worried about duplicates so I was going have it upload the image as a Random number

well here is my code you can probably understand what im going for through it anyways

```
<label for="file">Profile Pic:</label> <input type="file" name="ProfilePic" id="ProfilePic" /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

$ProfilePicName = $_FILES["ProfilePic"]["name"];
$ProfilePicType = $_FILES["ProfilePic"]["type"];
$ProfilePicSize = $_FILES["ProfilePic"]["size"];
$ProfilePicTemp = $_FILES["ProfilePic"]["tmp_name"];
$ProfilePicError = $_FILES["ProfilePic"]["error"];

$RandomAccountNumber = mt_rand(1, 99999);  
echo $RandomAccountNumber; 
move_uploaded_file($ProfilePicTemp, "Content/".$RandomAccountNumber.$ProfilePicType);
```

And then basicly after all this Im going try to get it to put that random number in my database

Someone gave me a new snippet that looks like it will do what I want but now the file isnt making it all the way to my directory

```
$RandomAccountNumber = uniqid();
echo $RandomAccountNumber;

move_uploaded_file($ProfilePicName,"Content/".$RandomAccountNumber);
```

Comment: Is there a question hidden in there somewhere?

Comment: trying to define a image before saving it to a directory without it having a duplicate id?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try using the php `uniqid` method to generate the unique id you need

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

```
$RandomAccountNumber = uniqid();
move_uploaded_file($ProfilePicTemp, "Content/" . $RandomAccountNumber);
```

Comment: hahah Thank you let me try to get this to work ill message you if I have any questions

Comment: hmmm I changed it to this 

      $RandomAccountNumber = uniqid();
      echo $RandomAccountNumber;
     
        move_uploaded_file($ProfilePicName,"Content/".$RandomAccountNumber);

But now the file isnt making it to the directory file??

Comment: @bushman, what happened to `.$ProfilePicType`? you removed it? Also make sure you have write permissions in that directory

Comment: @bushman, I think you need to leave it as `move_uploaded_file($ProfilePicTemp, "Content/".$RandomAccountNumber.$ProfilePicType);` since you need to find the file by using `$ProfilePicTemp`

Comment: hmm naw I used what you said and im getting these errors

Warning: move_uploaded_file(Content/50ac1204a6921image/jpeg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/34/9587634/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/Upload.php on line 208

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/home/content/34/9587634/tmp/phpPp3mDX' to 'Content/50ac1204a6921image/jpeg' in /home/content/34/9587634/html/MYDOMAIN.Com/Upload.php on line 208

Comment: The problem is the pictype is actually mime type which contains `/` in it. See me updated answer

Comment: hmm now they are making it through but they are loosing there file type so it come through as 5032ioifh random junk but not
5032ioifh.jpg

Sorry, I know your probably sighing right now im just a noob trying to grasp this but I think im hooked lol

Comment: Yup, your question was about the unique id. Your second question now is "How do I get the file extension when given a MIME type" which you can find an answer to at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147931/how-do-i-determine-the-extensions-associated-with-a-mime-type-in-php

Comment: hmm okay ill try to mess with that but I thought I could just add it as $ProfilePicType while moving it from the temp I mean I already know the file type.

Answer (score 5):

When I upload images, I usually save it as the `sha1()` of the image's contents (`sha1_file()`). That way, you get two birds with one stone: You'll never (if you do, go fill out the closest lottery) get duplicate file names, AND, you'll prevent duplicate images (because duplicate images would have the same checksum).

Then, you have a database to sort out which image is which, and correctly display them to the user.

Comment: I think this method would be bad. What if two users upload the same LOL cat and then one deletes it

Comment: @OmarJackman: It all depends on usage of course, you can make the file number user specific by adding a prefix, or grouping them into folders.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha do you use `sha1` or `sha1_file`?  Just curious

Comment: @mmmshuddup: I use `sha1_file()`. Many people (for some strange reason) like to use `sha1(file_get_contents())`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Oh ok. yeah that's weird.  I have actually never seen this method that's why I was curious.  You should provide a little snippet :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha probably because they don't realize that `sha1_file` exists

Comment: @OmarJackman yeah most likely.  it's a nice little trick I might use this one later if I need random/unique image names.

Comment: I really must say though that this solution seems more complicated than it needs to be. This is what the `uniqid()` method was made for. No need to read the contents of a file and execute `sha1` just to get a unique id.

Comment: @OmarJackman I totally agree, but this is still a nice method.

Comment: @OmarJackman: Unique ID is random, this isn't. I used this solution when I had a gallery project to store hundreds of thousands of images. You needed some sort of system for it, or you'd never leave that code alive.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha that's a lot of images.  Yeah in a situation like that, "_more complicated than it needs to be_" doesn't carry as much weight. I personally just let keep the original filename and append a (1) to the end if there are dupes.  It's worked for me so far with no issues.  But I'll keep this method in mind!

Answer (score 5):

This is what I use when uploading pictures: a combination of [session_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php), [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and a random string:

```
$rand = genRandomString();
$final_filename = $rand."_".session_id()."_".time();

function genRandomString() 
{
    $length = 5;
    $characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZ";

    $real_string_length = strlen($characters) ;     
    $string="id";

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) 
    {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $real_string_length-1)];
    }

    return strtolower($string);
}
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Since session ids can contain commans, would there be any issues with a comma in a filename using this method?

Answer (score 3):

`random != unique`

No matter what method you use to generate a 'random' file name you're probably going to want to do this to avoid collisions.

```
$path = '/path/to/directory/';
do {
    $filename = some_function();
} while( file_exists($path.$filename) );
```

It's not super-necessary, but if you're just looking for peace of mind in case of a one-in-a-million filename collision then those couple extra lines will do the trick.

Comment: Combine this with [Omar Jackman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13483456/486233) and it would be the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite [Coding Horror articles](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/hashtables-pigeonholes-and-birthdays.html) addresses why this approach is dumber than it looks, and you should use something like `uniqid` instead of `mt_rand(1, 99999);`...